# Hi , Google big query - bq fail load display file number how to get the file name

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm running the following bq command

```
bq load --source_format=CSV --skip_leading_rows=1 --max_bad_records=1000 --replace raw_data.order_20150131 gs://raw-data/order/order/2050131/* order.json
```

and 
getting the following message when loading data into bq .

```
*************************************
Waiting on bqjob_r4ca10491_0000014ce70963aa_1 ... (412s) Current status: DONE
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job
'orders:bqjob_r4ca10491_0000014ce70963aa_1': Too few columns: expected
11 column(s) but got 1 column(s). For additional help: http://goo.gl/RWuPQ
Failure details:
- File: 844 / Line:1: Too few columns: expected 11 column(s) but got
1 column(s). For additional help: http://goo.gl/RWuPQ

**********************************
```

The message display only the file number .

checked the files content most of them are good .

gsutil ls and the cloud console on the other hand display file names .

how can I know which file is it according to the file number?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some weird spacing introduced in the question, but if the desired path to ingest is "/*order.json" - that won't work: You can only use "*" at the end of the path when ingesting data to BigQuery.

Comment: I edit the original command not to contain the meaning . The space is by mistake . the command is working good for many files but for some it fails .just need to know how to translate the file id to file name .thanks

Comment: Right! Sorry for misunderstanding. Working with the team to have a better solution in the future (displaying the name of the file)